# Why isn't my scoped slot displaying anything?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to use Vue's [scoped slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Scoped-Slots):

**App.vue:**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <b-grid>
      <slot name="col" :col="2">
        <p>Some test</p>
      </slot>
    </b-grid>
  </div>
</template>
```

**BGrid.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="b-grid">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <template slot="col" scope="props">
          <div :class="'col' + props.col">This is a column</div>
        </template>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

However, the slot is displayed on the page. No errors in the console:

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="b-grid">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Note: I'm using Vue 2.3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the syntax flipped. You need to define a `slot` tag in the child component:

```
<div class="b-grid">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <slot name="col" :col="2"></slot>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then, in the parent component, use the `template` tag with the `slot` attribute to pass in the content to use for that slot:

```
<div id="app">
  <b-grid>
    <template slot="col" scope="props">
      <div :class="'col' + props.col">This is a column</div>
    </template>
  </b-grid>
</div>
```

[Here's a fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/jjpte3tt/)

Comment: Oh thanks ... but I wanted the `:class="'col' + props.col"` to be inside the BGrid component. Do you know how can I do that? Like in my original code.

Comment: It wouldn't make sense there, because the slot doesn't have a reference the scoped `props` variable. If you simply want to add a dynamic class from the parent template, just add it to the element, like `<div slot="col" class="col-2">This is a column</div>` [Example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jjpte3tt/1/)

Comment: I see thanks. So there's no way to add dynamic data to a slot inside a component.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. What you're passing as the content of the slot is all dynamic. What use case are you thinking of?

Comment: Like setting the number of the column: col-1, col-2. And then passing the content of that column.

Comment: You maybe should write out a new question for that with a code example. It's still hard to know what exactly you're trying to accomplish.